# RTP Packets to test RTSP Server

Tags: ffmpeg, media, rtsp, rtp

I am new to this domain, but I successfully setup RTSP server in one of the container and when running

```
./rtsp_media_server -l 8445 -s stream1 -p 8000
```

it is working fine. where `8445` is the expose port, `stream1` is the stream name and `8000` is the intake port

URL : `rtsp://<host>:8445/stream1`

But I need RTP packets to be sent to port `8000` so that I can test the my rtsp media server perfectly.

Do any online rtp server provides the same?

I can see many sample rtsp media server is there like `rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov` , which I can test in VLC media player. but not sure how to do with RTP packets.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can send H264 over RTP to port 8000 using gstreamer. 
The following gst-launch-1.0 command would do it for you in terminal. 
`gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=smpte ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8000`

Comment: can you explain what is videotestsrc ? can i give any video url or it should be in my system

Comment: videotestsrc is just a gstreamer plugin, it will generate video for you.

Comment: where is the video url or file source? I think it will create rtp packets based on some video right?